# DataSet prevent modified flag when setting the same value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

**Some Background**

I have a `DataColumn` "Col1" which is bound to an external WPF control through a binding:

```
<Setter Property="ControlProperty" Value="{Binding Col1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The problem is that the Control sometimes updates "ControlProperty" with the *same* value but this will let my `DataRow` think that it has changed although it actually has not. This behavior is not documented and its timing seems non-determinable.

**Actual Question**

So my question is if there is any way to prevent a `DataRow` from being flagged modified when the *same* value is written to it? Here is a code and a [Dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9VIrIv) to illustrate my expected behavior (Note that this is not my real code, this just is for demonstration purposes).

```
using System;
using System.Data;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Just setup the Set, nothing interesting
        var dat = new DataSet("Set1");
        var tab = new DataTable("Tab1");
        tab.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(int)));
        dat.Tables.Add(tab);
        tab.Rows.Add(123);
        var changes = dat.GetChanges();
        dat.Merge(changes);
        dat.AcceptChanges();

        Console.WriteLine("Row status is: {0}", tab.Rows[0].RowState); // Unchanged
        // Setting the same value will flag the Row "modified"
        // This is external code that I don't control
        tab.Rows[0]["Col1"] = tab.Rows[0]["Col1"];
        if (dat.HasChanges()) // Actual Value: True, Expected Value: False
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Row status is: {0}", tab.Rows[0].RowState); // Actual Value: Modified, Expected Value: Unchanged
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just had the same problem. from [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/DataRow.cs,331), it looks like you could attach a handler for the `ColumnChanged` event and call `CancelEdit` from there. will write up an answer if I find this working. as per your comment on the existing answer your sample code does not fully reflect your actual problem ("...external code that I don't control...")

Answer (score 0):

You have to just write one line in your code

```
        tab.Rows[0].AcceptChanges();
```

just after you assign same value to column as shown below.

```
 var dat = new DataSet("Set1");
            var tab = new DataTable("Tab1");
            tab.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(int)));
            dat.Tables.Add(tab);
            tab.Rows.Add(123);
            var changes = dat.GetChanges();
            dat.Merge(changes);
            dat.AcceptChanges();

            Console.WriteLine("Row status is: {0}", tab.Rows[0].RowState); // Unchanged
                                                                           // Setting the same value will flag the Row "modified"
            tab.Rows[0]["Col1"] = tab.Rows[0]["Col1"];
            tab.Rows[0].AcceptChanges();
            if (dat.HasChanges()) // Actual Value: True, Expected Value: False
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Row status is: {0}", tab.Rows[0].RowState); // Actual Value: Modified, Expected Value: Unchanged
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as explained in the background section It is external code which sets the Property which will trigger the Binding and thus set the Column. I sadly have no control over that external code